# Solidity how to set auto liqudity receiver adress

Tags: solidity

What is the liquidity receiver adress and how to include?

```
address public liquidityReceiver = ;
address public treasuryReceiver = ; 
address public riskFreeValueReceiver = ; 
uint256 public liquidityFee = 5; 
uint256 public treasuryFee = 2; 
uint256 public burnFee = 1;
uint256 public buyFeeRFV = 5;
uint256 public sellFeeTreasuryAdded = 2; 
uint256 public sellFeeRFVAdded = 3; 
uint256 public totalBuyFee = liquidityFee.add(treasuryFee).add(buyFeeRFV).add(burnFee);
uint256 public totalSellFee = totalBuyFee.add(sellFeeTreasuryAdded).add(sellFeeRFVAdded);
uint256 public feeDenominator = 100;
```

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

The address is whatever you want it to be... as long as it is valid.

Just slap it right after the "equals" sign... Variables (containers) on the left are assigned the values on the right of the "=".

I honestly suggest you get into Python or something first, because Solidity is a horrible first language.